# How to make blue shadows in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've noticed that in the real world, outdoor shadows seem to have a blue tint due to being lit by the sky. I tried to replicate this in three.js by adding a blue AmbientLight, but it doesn't seem to light in the shadows. How could I replicate this effect?

Comment: Your idea should work.. That is, some light that is casting shadows, and an blue ambient light that isn't. To see better what's happening, turn off the other lights,  and leave only the ambient light.

Comment: The ambient light works fine when I remove the other light. It seems like the shadows are being applied to all the lights for some reason.

Comment: Have you veryfied that castShadow is false for the ambient light

Comment: Ambient light doesn't cast shadow ever.

Comment: Shadows are applied to all lights in three.js currently. No I don't like it! Sadly you will have to dig into the fragment shader to fix this.

Comment: Oh, that's too bad. Is it possible to set the shadow color?